# Oblique perspective changes PlotRange of Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, projection

I am currently trying to adapt the example of Mathematica's documentation for [ViewMatrix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewMatrix.html) to `Plot3D`. This should implement an oblique/cavalier perspective for the 3d plot.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
g = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
tr = TransformationMatrix[
   RescalingTransform[{{-2, 7.5}, {0, 1}, {-2, 7}}]];
p = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
oblique[t_, 
   s_] := {{1, 0, s Cos[t], 0}, {0, 1, s Sin[t], 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0,
     0, 0, 1}};
Show[g, ViewMatrix -> {tr, oblique[3/4 \[Pi], 1/10] . p}, 
 PlotRegion -> {{0.25, 1}, {0.1, 1}}]
```

[image: The changed plot range demonstrated.]

The problem seems to be that the `RescalingTransform` or `TransformationMatrix` also influences the `PlotRange`. In the standard example of Mathematica's documentation, `Sin[x + y^2]`, this is somewhat minor, and I missed it at first. But in my (very non-minimal) example with lots of additional fiddling to have the right axes sizes, label sizes, legends and what not, it means I end up with a fraction of the Plot, essentially just a tiny strip and a single axis (and its label) showing.

At first, I tried solving it by adding the `PlotRegion -> {{0.25, 1}, {0.1, 1}}` to the options of `Show`, but this only solves the problem of cut-off parts of the plot; and even then not reliably. In my various attempts with my main (non-minimal) problem, I sometimes get cut-off plots filling the whole of the PlotRegion, making the values smaller and smaller then suddenly results in much too much padding. This additional padding can be seen in the example picture above.

I am happy to post the full example, but since it is rather long I tried unsuccessfully to put it in a spoiler tag to not distract too much from the main question. If someone has a good idea for how to leave that here, too, in way not blowing up the post too badly, that would be appreciated.

Long story short:

- How can I avoid the PlotRange being impacted by the transformations used for the oblique projection or how can I make up for that?
- How can I tell how to change the PlotRegion (or something similar) to avoid both superfluous image padding *and* the plot being cut off.